# Programmatically changing haproxy configuration file

Tags: java, haproxy

Is there any java program or api to change the content of  the configuration file of the haproxy? for example to append/remove few configuration dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Run a [thalassa](https://github.com/PearsonEducation/thalassa) server on the same machine as HAProxy and call its [http api](https://github.com/PearsonEducation/thalassa#http-api) from your Java program. It defines restful `POST` and `DELETE` interfaces for `registrations`, which are dynamically configured backends.

- [append documentation](https://github.com/PearsonEducation/thalassa#post-registrationsnameversionhostport)
- [remove documentation](https://github.com/PearsonEducation/thalassa#delete-registrationsnameversionhostport)

Comment: thalassa looks very intersting, but is it stable enough to be used in productive systems ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding, that's a great question. I've never tried it in production myself. [Contacting the maintainers](https://www.npmjs.org/package/thalassa-aqueduct) for feedback might be your best course of action. Let us know!

Comment: I tried it out the last few days and works okay but obviously has so bugs. Since it is open source and I might be able to handle some bugs myself I will probably use it.

Comment: so i added a more detailed answer of your solution listing the current thalassa toolchain

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the Answer of allonhadaya I tried out thalassa.

Pearson Eduction who are the main contributes build a complete stack around:
https://github.com/PearsonEducation

So in your example you would probably use three of their components

1. Thalassa (Service Directory Service)
2. Thalassa Http Client
3. Thalassa Aqueduct

The Service Directory is the central service manager. With the application itself (if it is a node application there are predefined compontens) or with the Thalassa HTTP Client you register your service (application) at the service directory. In your case with your existing java application, using the HTTP standalone client might be a good way to start.

Thalassa Aqueduct ist the bridge to the HA-Proxy. It connects the Service Directory with the HA-Proxy configuration. At the moment it has (only) some REST Methods to also configure the HA-Proxy Frontends and Backends. But a quite OK Webinterface to see how many connections are handled and balanced right now.